# How to remove quotes " " from a column of a Spark dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame.

```
+-------+-----+
|   Name|  age|
+-------+-----+
|  "aaa"|  111|
|"asasa"| 8888|
| "2323"|  999|
|"wewwe"|99999|
+-------+-----+
```

I want it to be like :

```
+-------+-----+
|   Name|  age|
+-------+-----+
|  aaa  |  111|
| asasa | 8888|
| 2323  |  999|
| wewwe |99999|
+-------+-----+
```

How can I achieve this in Spark 2 using pyspark code?

If any solution, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.withColumn("Name", F.regexp_replace("Name", "\"", ""))
```